# jQuery Load ajax method not loads calender plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-2, calendar

**Jquery Code**

```
  $('#afterServiceSelect').die('click').live('click', function () {

  var petKeys = $('#pets input:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join('+');

   $('#available-dates').load('/PetBooking/GetAvailableDatesForServce/', { 'providerKey': '<%:Model.Provider.Key%>', 'ownerKey': '<%:Model.Owner.Key%>', 'serviceId': $('#ddlService').val(), 'petKeys': petKeys, 'numberOfDays': 90 }, function () {

            });

         return false;
  });
```

**Main page HTML**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <div id="available-dates">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetAvailableDatesForServce(string providerKey, string ownerKey, string serviceId, string petKeys, string numberOfDays)
        {
            var bookingFacadeService = new BookingFacadeService();

            var model = new AppointmentViewModel
                {
                    AvailableDates = bookingFacadeService.GetAvailableDates(providerKey, ownerKey, serviceId, petKeys.Split('+'), Convert.ToInt32(numberOfDays)).ToList()
                };

            return PartialView("Dates", model);
        }
```

**Dates partial view**

```
    var value = dates.Any() ? dates.Select(d => d.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Join(",") : "";
     var monthCount = ((DateTime.Today.AddDays(90).Month - DateTime.Today.Month + 1) + 12) % 12; %>

<div id="dates" class="inline-multi-calendar" data-multi="true" data-months="<%: monthCount %>"
    data-min="<%: min %>" data-max="<%: max %>" data-disallowed="<%= string.Join(",", Model.UnavailableDates.Select(d => d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToArray()) %>"
    data-value="<%: value %>">
</div>
```

**UI should be**

[image]

**Problem :** When I load calender like above it doesn't load the calender.In other words partial page loads without calender (other stuff loads correctly).

But when I load full page without ajax load method it shows with calender control.

So my **question** is how to use Ajax load with calender control (my feeling is calender plugin not load with ajax call.So how can I load that with ajax load method)?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the ajax load method, or do you want to get rid of the partial loading problem, or something else?

Comment: @Paul I want to use ajax load method and also with calender control. Currently calender not loads with ajax load method.